# LimeJS Rounded Border

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, limejs

I want to display a thin rounded corner border around my game.  Can I leverage the RoundedRect for this, or do I have to do something else?  I see it doesn't come natively, so I was wondering how it's done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the entire game into a lime.RoundedRect and add a border to it.

```
// requirements
goog.require('lime.RoundedRect');

// in your main function
var gameContainer = new lime.RoundedRect();
gameContainer.setStroke(12,'#000000');
gameContainer.appendChild(/* the rest of your code here */);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with LimeJS but you could try using [`border-radius`](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) as a CSS property on the element the game renders to.